# Active strings in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker

There is a facility in WinEdit that: to type `$ $` or `( )` or `{ }` or `[ ]` we need to hit corresponding key only once. For example, if we type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> we get `( )` directly. This is possible in WinEdit by making some settings in active string. My question is does such facility is available in Texmaker?

Answer (score 1):

In TeXmaker you can add the `$...$` using `Ctrl + Shift + M` for an equation in the middle of the text, or  `Ctrl + Shift + N` for an numbered displayed equation (inserts the `equation` environment.

You can check this and all the default shortcuts in `Options>Configure TeXmaker` and in the window the fourth window: Shortcuts is where you can edit them. But if you don't want to change them but add new such as the shortcuts you explained, then I think the best choice to create your own shortcuts is got to `User>User Commands` and there configure until 5 commands with the combination keys the program gives you.

Perhaps isn't the most comfortable for you or the answer you was waiting, but is the best I know. I hope you find it useful